# iOS app working without essential frameworks linked

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, core-graphics, core-image

i am working on an iOS app which is able to make videos out of single screenshots. I therefore need things like `CVPixelBufferRef`, `CGContextRef` and `AVAssetWriter`. Currently the app is working fine but there is one thing I do not understand:

For example, `CVPixelBufferRef` is a reference to a Core Video image buffer and is part of the `CoreVideo` framework which I haven't linked to my app. 
The same applies to `CGContextRef` which is part of the `CoreGraphics` framework which I also haven't linked. (Or `CABasicAnimation` which is part of the `QuartzCore` framework)

How is it possible that my app is working fine, without essential frameworks? Do I no longer need to link these frameworks?

I would appreciate any hint.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be because of "Link Frameworks Automatically" build settings.

[image]

From Apple docs

> When a source file includes a header from a framework that supports
>   modules, the compiler generates extra information in the object file
>   to automatically link in that framework. The result is that, in most
>   cases, you will not need to specify a separate list of the frameworks
>   to link with your target when you use a framework API that supports
>   modules.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. I searched for it before, but couldn't find anything.